# PHP array_unique without index

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to find something similar to `array_unique()` to the extent or removing all the duplicates from an array. However in this particular case I need a comma spaced array as the result rather than an key value pair. What I'd like to do is avoid running this through a loop to do it, if I can.

So if theres something like `array_unique()` or something I can apply to my array there after to strip the numeric index out then I am all ears for suggestions.

Currently I am building the initial array through a loop, this look cycles over 5 to 150,000 entries of which one particular entry can have any of about 1,000 possible 3 dot style versioning numbers. This is what I am building this array of. So I have many duplicates put into the array

example:

```
$myarray = array();
foreach($obj as $prod)
{
   //cycling over the master loop adding all my other stuff and building it out..
   $myarray[] = $prod['version'];
}
```

which gives me quite a large array in the format I'd like just

```
Array(
   "1.0.0",
   "1.0.1",
   "3.0.2220",
   "2.0.0",
   "2.0.1",
   "1.8.11",
   "3.0.2220",
   "3.0.2220",
   "2.0.0",
   "2.0.0",
   "2.0.0"
)
```

Where afte the loop is complete I do.

```
$myarray = array_unique($myarray);
```

Which leaves me with an array like

```
Array(
  [0] = "1.0.0",
  [1] = "1.0.1",
  [2] = "3.0.2220",
  [3] = "2.0.0",
  [4] = "2.0.1",
  [5] = "1.8.11",
)
```

Which is not desired, what is desired as the end result is..

```
Array(
   "1.0.0",
   "1.0.1",
   "3.0.2220",
   "2.0.0",
   "2.0.1",
   "1.8.11",
)
```

Where I can then sort it out to list in order earliest to latest versions..

Comment: Even elements in your desired array have some kind of an index. Are you having issues with displaying this, or outputting it/exporting it?

Comment: does *3.0.2220* comes before *2.0.0* in *earliest to latest versions*? What kind of sorting you are looking for ? And for your information , even associative array also has an index :)

Comment: `usort()` where I am sorting versions greater to lesser currently, which I have working. The sort wasn't the issue so much as my brain fart that I was suffering from upon asking the question, which was actually related to something I was actually working on from the front end and not actually occuring on the backend like I thought it was initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
Array(
  [0] = "1.0.0",
  [1] = "1.0.1",
  [2] = "3.0.2220",
  [3] = "2.0.0",
  [4] = "2.0.1",
  [5] = "1.8.11",
)
```

and this:

```
Array(
   "1.0.0",
   "1.0.1",
   "3.0.2220",
   "2.0.0",
   "2.0.1",
   "1.8.11",
)
```

are the **same** thing, in PHP all arrays have an index, in the last example it's just that is not printing them, but they are there, and if you have not explicitly specified the indexes, they are just sequencial integer numbers starting from zero, like the first example.

In your last example, the one which apparently has no indexes, if we call it `$array` we can do the following to print its indexes:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key; //this will print the indexes of the array
}
```

Comment: Im looking for a list of sorts, sorry, its one of those mornings.. but I just solved my own issue, it was a misstep on my part on the javascript side of things I am doing.. that tripped me up

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting an array without keys?  Every array has keys.